# Google maps ad hyperlink to country marker

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-markers

On my website, I have a google map to show the places i've been to with country markers on them. Is there any way to turn them into hyperlinks so that when a user clicks those markers, it leads them to a webpage with the photos from that particular country?
Here is my code:

```
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
function initMap() {
    var myLatLng = {lat: 51.491217, lng: -0.142822};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: myLatLng,
      zoom: 1,
      streetViewControl: false
    });
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});

    // Try HTML5 geolocation.
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var pos = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        };

        infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
        map.setCenter(pos);
      }, function() {
        handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
      });
    } else {
      // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
      handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    }
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    function getCountry(country) {
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': country }, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
               map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
               var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                   map: map,
                   position: results[0].geometry.location
               }); 
            } else if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) {    
        setTimeout(function() {
            Geocode(address);
        }, 200);
        } else {
              alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
            }
        });
    }
    getCountry('France');
    getCountry('Sweden');
    getCountry('Croatia');
    getCountry('New Zealand');
    getCountry('Laos');
    getCountry('Vietnam');
    getCountry('Tonga');
    getCountry('Vanuatu');
    getCountry('France');
    getCountry('Indonesia');
    getCountry('Malaysia');
    getCountry('Samoa');
  }



  function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
    infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
    infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                          'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                          'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
  }
</script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add an event listener to your markers. So something like this would work:

```
marker.addListener('click', function() {
    window.location.href = 'http://example.com';
});
```

For more examples of an event listener on markers refer to the docs here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#animate

Comment: As I am new to google maps and javascript, could I please have a full-code implementation as I don't know how and where to put it? Thanks!

Comment: @Felix put it right after the line you declare your `marker`